# Eclipse how to change color of tab for different project?

Tags: eclipse, colors, ide, themes, ide-customization

I work on different projects open on eclipse, and i would like to differentiate the tabs of each project with different colors, like i do in netbeans as shown in the picture below.
I searched in preferences but i was unable to find a way.
Is it possible to do it?
Thank you.

Netbeans
[image: Netbeans]

Eclipse
[image: Eclipse]

Comment: Eclipse doesn't support this.

Comment: Your are asking for the X of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Eclipse does not have solution X built-in and I'm not aware of a [plugin that implements solution X](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search?search_api_fulltext=color+tabs). A solution other than X for the root problem Y might be [Eclipse Mylyn](https://eclipse.dev/mylyn/), depending on what Y is in your case.

Comment: There is no xy problem here, because the xy problem is a communication misunderstanding in which a user's real problem X, is unclear, because, rather than directly asking how to solve X, he asks for support in solving a secondary problem Y that he believes will help him solve X.

The X problem here, (and my direct question), is how to color tabs different colors for different projects. And I brought an example case of how I do this with Netbeans.
What would be the Y problem in this case?

Comment: The one you believe having different colors would solve, not how to set different colors.

Comment: There is nothing to solve. It was just an aesthetic question.
Why do the answers have to be so tedious?
Just answer no. it is not possible.
I will continue to use eclipse without problems even if it doesn't have colored tabs ;))
"...when people can't help, then they criticize..."